# Correspondences between syntactic categories and human cognition: are telic classes missing (in English)?

Tags: grammar

A basic but rich question (to me) seems to be, we have these familiar lexical categories that come up again and again across languages, but why? Nouns, verbs, adjectives, adverbs, prepositional phrases, etc. Furthermore, we have linguistic concepts or forms that similarly recur: clauses, subject-predicate, tense, even number, and so on.

The simple question “why”, especially for subject-predicate: why is that the basis of communication?

Subject-predicate seems semantically something like, “thing + attribute”: you reference some thing, and add information to it.

One reason I find this confusing is when we are told that lexical categories exist on a higher level of the language system than *concepts*. It seems locally like a convenient way to explain how “I am a doctor” reflects “doctor” as a noun in English, whereas “я доктор” in Russian (maybe) could analyze “doctor” as a verb? Actually, that doesn’t sound feasible, but I think I heard someone say that once. The point being, the fact that we can derive words from each other (nominalized adjectives, etc.) may conveniently lead to the assertion that there is a pre-syntactic, unified thing called a “concept”, which simply gets inserted into a syntactic form, but I am not sure that is that strictly or certainly implied, anymore, and it seems like it leads to problems in analysis.

I think it seems more natural to think that a lot of human cognition is heavily influenced by the syntactic categories we use, for things. For example, instead of claiming there is a semantically integrated but purely a-syntactic “concept” underlying every conceptual element in a language (tree and bird, but not “grammar” words like “the”), that it may be hard if not impossible for us to “think” about anything without our subconscious mind assigning it a syntactic role. Even if I take the word “the” and call it “the-ness”, it allows my mind to conceive of “the general phenomenon of being “the”, it’s connotations, implications, associations, etc.” That means, we can *transmute* a word class into another one by their shared associations, taking away some latent understanding and adding some different ones, but that doesn’t mean there is a “second layer” in cognition where phantom concepts are waiting to be given syntactic form. Maybe “concepts” are an implied idea, a composite sum, an average, of similar words of different lexical class, but mnemonic associations are pegged to the token of words themselves - the words come before the concepts, not vice versa. (Possibly.)

This means that the so-called “language of thought” *is* basically just syntax. Every syntactic form we see hints directly at the parameters of human cognition itself; maybe it’s less mysterious than we think. We have words for numbers because we can think in numbers. We have “thing”-words because we think about the world (an initially disorganized flux of sensory data) in terms of “things”. And so on, for verbs, adjectives, subject-predicate forms, etc.

This made me wonder why we do not see more particular lexical or syntactic categories, then. What if every semantic or ontological category was studied as a syntactic category, as well? Maybe the class of color words has extremely subtle differences in behavior from say, a different class of adjectives, like size: maybe it’s because of the very inherent properties and behaviors of colors, that our thinking about them is realized in terms of arbitrary structural elements (sounds, words, morphemes, inflections, language) that reconstructs them as (we think) they are.

What interests me very much are the 5 “wh-“ questions, who, what, where, when, and why. It seems like they span some fundamental “modes” that “things” in human thought can take the shape of - but I was wondering if “why” - *purpose*, *causation*, or *intention* is noticeably absent, as a pure, independently realizable syntactic form? Does any other language have that? Could we construct a language that does, to consider what expressive ease it maybe could furnish us with?

Which is the most general - anything at all.

What and who subdivide things (nouns) in animate, living, being, human, person, sentient, autonomous, free will, agency, subject, etc., vs. thing, object, inanimate, non-sentient, etc.

When is the obvious dimension of time; ‘how’ encompasses both verbs and static qualities it seems, which divide into adverbs and adjectives - ‘in what way’, the difference between a thing/substance/element/referent/noun and the other side of the ‘clause’, something about it, pegging information to it, what did it do, how is it like, give me more information about it, and so on. “How” also encompasses things like theta-roles and noun cases, where a thing can be agentive or stative, or be mentioned as an instrument or a location.

Noticeably absent I feel is ‘why’. We have fundamental and particular words for the idea of causation, purpose and telos - “because” - “for” - “in order to” - but it strikes me, why wouldn’t we have a particular inflection, for that idea?

I was thinking that “why” corresponds syntactically most to discourse - to sequences of clauses-propositions-assertions, where there may be an entire class of its own in language, allowing you to express ideas about other entire clauses, themselves. You can say, “The belief *that* the curriculum should be taught *is* stupid.”

You were able to assign propositional meaning to not just things/referents, but to clauses themselves - somewhat like meta-language or meta-syntax. I wonder if subordination is ultimately about letting humans self-reflect on propositions, and express attitudes about them, and maybe have their own particular class or “language” about what kinds of relations two propositions can have - there can be a reversal of expectations (as in coordination, “but”), simultaneity, “and”, and also epistemic or ontic matters, “Sarah *thinks* that…”, “I hope…”, and so on.

Then within this category of meta-propositions, somehow - perhaps mysteriously - humans have a deep, innate, natural sense of *causation*, which is something like *why* a number of propositions hang together, why they may imply each other, somehow.

But I ask: why not see that get as grammaticalized as everything else, in language?

Considering language as (potentially) a deeply arbitrary mapping between the observable, perceivable, manipulable states of any medium (sounds, an abacus, time, color, whatever), and critically, the *language of thought* (even more esoteric aspects of conscious experience, edge-cases - like pairing a highly particular glyph, in a Pavlovian way, with an extremely unique sensory experience, like a particular state of mind, dream, musical moment, etc.) - it would not be far fetched to see ideas of causation or purpose at least as inflected forms, and not just stand-alone words. And we could also ask how rich a sub-classification of “purpose” or “telos”, or just “implied relevance”, is possible - a conlang like Ithkuil tries to grammaticalize tons of such things - but in a natural language, do we see any languages across the world which sub-divide “why / because” much more fine-grained into differential sub-cases, and which can even inflect to express them?

Perhaps Turkic languages, which have a “reported speech” case, or poly-synthetic American languages, or any fusional language, perhaps Gaelic, or any expressive, inflected languages, like classical Latin, Greek, Old Slavic, and/or Sanskrit?

Comment: You should know that, as a general rule, linguists do not find the distinction between telic and atelic verbs to be grammatically meaningful. It's counterintuitive, but it's the truth. Here is a monograph that might help answer some of your questions: https://www.rickmor.x10.mx/lexical_semantics.html

Comment: _lexical categories exist on a higher level of the language system than concepts_ is not true.  Concepts are not part of language, they're part of thought, which has something to do with talking, but is not language, nor organized like language, and can't be studied like language because human thought is all imaginary, where language has data.